# Meteor login hangs during mongo errors

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

We've been experiencing some odd problems with Meteor/Mongo recently, it seems to be related to mongo instances dropping - but I thought meteor had the resiliancy to deal with this.

We're running about 10 Meteor servers for different applications all connecting to the same database. A replica set with 3 data-bearing, visible, voting nodes, and a single data-bearing, invisible vote=0, priority=0 node we use for taking backups.

Each server uses a connection string which specifies each of the three mongo nodes as seed nodes, and a readPreference of nearest, write preference of majority. `mongodb://user:password@mongo1,mongo2,mongo3/db?replicaSet=rs&w=majority&wtimeoutMS=10000&readPreference=nearest`

we're facing two apparently separate issues:

1. This morning, `mongo1` crashed - it was NOT the primary - after restoring this server, about 90% of the application continued to function correctly, subscriptions worked, the UI loaded, etc. However, some methods (not even all of them) hung, in some cases this method was the login method. In other cases it related to image upload. This only impacted users of 2/10 servers (presumably the ones that were closest to `mongo1`)
2. About 2 days ago, we had a primary failover - we waited 2 minutes to see if the servers would recover, when they didn't we went in and manually restarted them. By the time we got to number 8, the final two servers had fixed themselves. This took approximately 6 minutes.

So, my questions:

1. How long should a primary failover take in Meteor (lets assume the primary election finishes in 10 seconds) how long after that does Meteor start fully working again, can this be configured?
2. What could cause specific meteor methods to fail on a specific server, with no error logs anywhere (meteor console, kadira, or mongo logs) the servers are identical.

Comment: Can you simulate the cluster in a vm cluster or in a staging environment? Regarding the second point I would try to replicate the steps to cause the method fails to see if there is a pattern (e.g. always the same function) that seems to be the cause. Don't forget, that there has always been buggy code even in corporate software with x revisions that nobody identified until it broke. Regarding production stability and failsafeness I have experienced phusion passenger as a very reliable companion. Beyond that you may try to get more attention from the meteor but also(!) from the mongo community.

Comment: @Jankapunkt, thanks for the ideas - we're pretty sure the functions involved aren't buggy (or at least are buggy in ways that produce errors), particularly given that one of them is the meteor defined login method. Our initial working theory was that all methods that required write access were failing - however we found this was not the case.